# How to clear Chrome inspect network tab by shortcut keys?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to clear the network tab in Chrome developer tools inside the Chrome browser. I know that their is an button for that but what's the shortcut keys for doing that?
Are their anywhere cheatsheet for chrome developer tool or chrome shortcuts?
please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please only press double Ctrl+E